# Codeigniter 2.1 - remove part of the uri

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have standard type of uri:

```
www.example.com/controler/function/id
```

How can I remove id part form the url (it is always a number)?

Comment: Will there be anything after it? Do you want to remove it from a string programmatically, or do you want to re-route it? (And if the latter - why?)

Comment: Hmm, I need it as aesthetic thing, simply not to be visible, so I guess I want to remove it from a string programmatically.

Comment: Do you still need the ID in the function itself?

Comment: Yes, I need it for DB query. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You could pass it as POST data. But it really depends on what it's for.

Comment: I have a hyperlink - **<a href"<?php echo base_url() ?>controller/function/id">exampleXY</a>**. When it is clicked, you go to desired location.

Comment: I think, you should look into routing: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is really so terrible, you *can* use the History API to hide it:

```
if(history.replaceState) {
    history.replaceState(null, '', 'http://www.example.com/controller/function');
}
```

It won't work on older browsers, but if it's only for aesthetic purposes (and those had better be important; otherwise, don't do this!) then it should be fine.